# PriorityQueue sorting is not maintaining the alphabetical order if the values are equal

Tags: java, sorting

My problem is something like this:

I have **TestQ** class

```
class TestQ{
 public void main(String[] args){
    PriorityQueue<Request> requestQ = new PriorityQueue<Request>(5, new SortRequest());
    //...
 }
}
```

My **Request** class has two fields along with getters and setters.

```
int siteId;
int timestamp;
```

And **SortRequest** class is something like this

```
class SortRequest implements Comparator<Request>{
   public int compare(Request r1, Request r2) {
       return r1.getTimeStamp()-r2.getTimeStamp();
   }
}
```

In **TestQ** class I'm taking user input for siteId and Timestamp. Constraint is that 
siteId should be unique but timestamp could be same or different.
(say siteIds are 1,2,3,4,5 for 5 sites).

Since I'm sorting my Request Queue based on timestamp value. And in case if timestamp of two/more sites are equal, then I expect the PriorityQueue to sort it according to siteId so that lower siteId should precede the higher one. 
I'm not getting the expected. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: All you compare is timestamps; what does siteId have to do with anything?

Comment: Well, my requirement is that if the timestamps of two sites(say site 2 and site 3) are equal then site 2's request should precede site 3's request.

Comment: And I'm saying if that's your requirement, then why does your `Comparator` only compare timestamps?

Comment: Ya got it. I should compare siteId as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple modification to `compare()`:

```
public int compare(Request r1, Request r2) {
    int diff = Integer.compare(r1.getTimeStamp(), r2.getTimeStamp());

    if (diff != 0)
        return diff;

    return Integer.compare(r1.siteId(), r2.siteId());
}
```

Use [`Integer.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) to compare the values, as opposed to subtracting them. The latter can lead to overflow issues and incorrect results (thanks @Vash for pointing that out).

Comment: You should not use this logic. You should return 0 -1 or 1.

Comment: @Vash Ok, I see where you're coming from. Fair enough, I'll edit the code.

Comment: giving error cannot find symbol: method compare(int)
location: class java.lang.Integer    Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Comparator need to be like this

```
class SortRequest implements Comparator<Request>{
   public int compare(Request r1, Request r2) {
      if(r1.getTimeStamp()!=r2.getTimeStamp())
         return new Integer(r1.getTimeStamp()).compareTo(r2.getTimeStamp());
      if(r1.getSiteId()!=r2.getSiteId())
         return new Integer(r1.getSiteId()).compareTo(r2.getSiteId());
      return 0;      
   }
}
```